# Inconsistent LaunchKernels[8] versus LaunchKernels[] on Linux?

Tags: parallelization, linux

**Context**

I am interested in doing parallel computation on a linux machine.

**Odd behaviour**

When I chose explicitly the number of kernels

```
(~)> math
Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= LaunchKernels[8]
```

(* {KernelObject[1, local], KernelObject[2, local], ….
, KernelObject[8, local]}
*)

Whereas if I don't specify the number of Kernels

```
In[1]:= LaunchKernels[]
```

I get

wolfram: Command not found.

wolfram: Command not found.

...

wolfram: Command not found.

**Question**

> Could anyone please reproduce what seems to be a (admittedly minor)  Bug?

This seems to hold true for Mathematica 10.3 and 12.

---

Note that If one does not bother explicitly launching the kernels it does not work either

```
(~)> math
Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= ParallelTable[Pause[1],{4}]//AbsoluteTiming
Launching kernels...
```

I get again

wolfram: Command not found.

wolfram: Command not found.

---

Finally note that on a mac it works as it should

```
In[1]:= ParallelTable[Pause[1], {4}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Out[1]= {2.78291,{Null,Null,Null,Null}}

Comment: Did you ever configure any kernels manually? Check `$ConfiguredKernels` (or `$ConfiguredKernels // InputForm` if needed). Kernel configuration can be done through the preferences dialog, so you may have set it even if you never used `$ConfiguredKernel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference between `LaunchKernel[n]` and `LaunchKernels[]` is that `LaunchKernels[n]` will launch `n` kernels on the local machine while `LaunchKernels[]` will launch whatever is in [`$ConfiguredKernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ConfiguredKernels.html).

Most likely, you have configured subkernels manually through the graphical interface (Preferences dialog), and that configuration is no longer valid.

You can check/set the kernel configuration programmatically though `$ConfiguredKernels` or graphically in the preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. I don't use the frontend for this test. If I type In[1]:=                                                                                              $ConfiguredKernels
Out[1]= {16 local kernels, 32 kernels on b6}. So this is not inconsistent with LaunchKernel[32] in principle, but in practice it seems to be.

Comment: I should also say that this is not consistent with the number of cores available  which is 40. `In[9]:= RunProcess["lscpu", "StandardOutput"]
Out[9]= Architecture:          x86_64
        CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
        Byte Order:            Little Endian
        CPU(s):                40`

Comment: This confirms that you (or someone else) created a subkernel configuration manually. Notice the presence of non-local kernels. Revert this configuration to the default. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConfiguringAndMonitoring.html I am not sure how to permanently change the configuration without the front end, but assuming that it was changed manually, the same steps could be used to revert it ...

Comment: "I should also say that this is not consistent with the number of cores available which is 40." The maximum number of subkernels may be limited by your license. Check `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses`.

Comment: One thought: Are you using the Lightweight Grid or some similar technology which automatically discovers available kernels on the network? I have never used it and have no experience with it. If you really did not ever change the subkernel configuration, maybe such a system did. Also: does the computer named `b6` have the same version of Mathematica that you are using here, or a much older one that uses `math` instead of `wolfram`?

Comment: I have removed .Mathematica and relaunched and now it has `$ConfiguredKernels   {ï8 local kernels}
`

Comment: @chris, rather than deleting, I would encourage you to self-answer with the likely problem, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by the accepted answer the problem arose because of artefacts from a (forgotten) past lightweight grid setting hidden within the .Mathematica directory .

The solution is to displace this directory and after a restart copy the mathpass back to License .

Incidentally it explains recurent misuses of the cluster which did not impress our system manager!